# c# is it possbile to change object type in c#?

Tags: c#

Here is the code problem, QuotationReportV5CT is a report service object, now i have to add some condition if the variable userGroup is "TEST", quotereport should use QuotationReportV6CT but not QuotationReportV5CT, can i convert QuotationReportV5CT object to QuotationReportV6CT ?

```
                QuotationReportV5CT quotereport = new QuotationReportV5CT();
                QuotationReportV6CT quotereport1 = new QuotationReportV6CT();
                //quotereport.Dispose();
                //quotereport = null;
                //Object quotereport = new Object();
                if (userGroup == "TEST") {
                    quotereport = (QuotationReportV6CT)quotereport1;
                    //QuotationReportV6CT quotereport = new QuotationReportV6CT();
                }

                quotereport.Parameters["QuotationId"].Value = quotationId;
```

Comment: A little more Context would be helpful. Assuming V5 and V6 are two completely disjoint classes: no way. If they both implement a common interface: use that. If V6 "is-a" V5 (i.e. V6 inherits V5) then the cast should work.

Comment: ^^ However, I suspect this would be better solved using a different pattern, but to suggest one, more context would be needed.

Comment: public partial class QuotationReportV6CT : DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport , seem like i can declare quotereport as DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport, in the if else condition, i can do the cast

Comment: There you go. A base class. Pretty much the same idea as an interface.